# how to call a function saved in string

Tags: c++

if i have:

```
void print_1();

void print_2();

void print_3();
```

and i have another function called `valid();` which return an integer

i want to declare a `string = "print_x());"`

and i want to replace `x` by the value returned by `valid();`

for example if the value returned by `valid();` is `3`

```
         =====> the string will be ("print_3();")
```

and then i want to call the function which saved in the string variable,
i want to make call like this:

```
print_3();
```

how can i do that

Comment: In c/c++ there is no elegant way, you'll need an if/else which calls the correct function.

Comment: use c# and reflections ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is "not possible directly".

You can, however, simply do:

```
switch (code) {
    case 1: call_1(); break;
    case 2: call_2(); break;
}
```

etc...

Comment: You should show the OP a way, how to translate the string to `code` (e.g. using a `std::map` or s.th. alike), or give a sample with `if {} else if {} else {}` statements comparing the strings.

Comment: @g-makulik Actually, OP basically has an integer-ready-form from valid() which he can use. I would provide an extended solution if more code was listed in the first place. I helped with a particular problem the OP was wondering about.

Comment: so, what is the best way to select one of 11 functions??

Comment: @user3084126: umm ... just continue with `case 3: ..`, `case 4: ..` and so on? (But an alternate way could be an array of functions. OTOH since you had to ask *this*, stick with a switch until you know more.)

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have any support for that kind of programming.

If you only have three functions then you can parse the string and write a switch statement to call the desired function. However, I suspect that you are looking for something like the `eval()` function that is found in scripting languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua etc. C++ has no such thing.

Comment: But you can write such functionality, for a known set of functions.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, that's what my second paragraph says

Comment: so, what is the best way to select one of 11 functions??

Comment: It's still a switch statement. It's just longer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed, your exact requirement is not fulfilled by C++. But you can consider the following code as an alternative to `switch` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;                                                                 
void print_0()                                                                       
{                                                                                    
    cout << "Print 0\n";                                                             
}                                                                                    
void print_1()                                                                       
{                                                                                    
    cout << "Print 1\n";                                                             
}                                                                                    
void print_2()                                                                       
{                                                                                    
    cout << "Print 2\n";                                                             
}     
typedef void(*FunctionPointer)();
FunctionPointer functionPointers[] = {&print_0, &print_1, &print_2};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int return_value = 0;
    functionPointers[return_value]();
    return_value = 1;
    functionPointers[return_value]();
    return_value = 2;
    functionPointers[return_value]();
    return 0;
}
```

The code uses an array of function pointers to call a specific function as intended by the return value.

Comment: thanks pro, but i will use if else
i think its easier

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I would do. Much simpler like this than a switch.

Comment: It depends. Switch is easier at beginners level. But once you get habituated to pointers, it makes more sense to use codes like these.